# Domain and range of $\arccos\sqrt{\log_{\lfloor x\rfloor}\frac{|x|}x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Find the domain and range of 
>   $$\arccos\sqrt{\log_{\lfloor x\rfloor}\frac{|x|}x}$$

I have written conditions for the domain:
$$\lfloor x\rfloor\ne1,\ \lfloor x\rfloor>0,\ x\ne0,\ \frac{|x|}x>0$$
$$-1\le \sqrt{\log_{\lfloor x\rfloor}\frac{|x|}x}\le1$$
My textbook doesn't state the last condition, which I do not seem to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use $\;\log_{\lfloor x\rfloor}\;$ , then it must be $\;x\ge2\;$ , so that $\;|x|=x\;$ , and then we can write:

$$\log_{\lfloor x\rfloor}\frac{|x|}x=\log_{\lfloor x\rfloor}1=0$$

and the question becomes pretty simple. Check if there's some mistake in your definition.

Comment: why x must be greater than or equal to 2

Comment: Because otherwise the basis is a forbidden number. Remember that the basis of a logarithm must be a positive number *different from one* . Can you see now why?